# Spark group-by aggregation in a dataset containing a map

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a java POJO

```
class MyObj{
  String id;
  Map<KeyObj, ValueObj> mapValues;
  //getters and //setters(omitted)
}
```

I have a spark dataset

```
Dataset<MyObj> myDs = .....
```

My dataset has a list of values but there are duplicate Ids. How do I combine the duplicate account Ids and aggregate the Key values pairs into one Map for that Id using Spark groupBy.
Thanks for your help.

So I have:

```
ID.     Map
----------------------------------
1000   [(w -> wer), (D -> dfr)]
1000   [(g -> gde)]
1001   [(k -> khg), (v -> vsa)]
```

And I need this:

```
ID.   Map
----------------------------------
1000   [(w -> wer), (D -> dfr), (g -> gde)]
1001   [(k -> khg), (v -> vsa)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) the original maps so that each entry of each map is a row of its own. Then you can group over the `id` column and restore the maps with [map_from_arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#map_from_arrays-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-):

```java
myDs.select(col("id"),explode(col("mapValues"))) //1
   .groupBy("id")
   .agg(collect_list("key").as("keys"), collect_list("value").as("values")) //2
   .withColumn("map", map_from_arrays(col("keys"), col("values"))) //3
   .drop("keys", "values") //4
   .show(false);
```

1. [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) the maps into single rows. The new column names will be `key` and `value`
2. When grouping by `id` [collect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_list-java.lang.String-) all keys and values into arrays, resulting in one array with keys and one array with values per `id`
3. Use [map_from_arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#map_from_arrays-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) to transform the keys and values arrays back into a single map
4. drop the intermediate columns

The result is

```
+----+------------------------------+
|id  |map                           |
+----+------------------------------+
|1000|[D -> dfr, w -> wer, g -> gde]|
|1001|[v -> vsa, k -> khg]          |
+----+------------------------------+
```